# Prove that $R$ is a ring with division.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm having problems trying to know if my proof is wrong or not. The problem states:

> Let $R$ a ring with 1, not necessary commutative, such that for every $a\in R\setminus\{0\}$, there exists $b\in R\setminus\{0\}$ (which depends on $a$) such that $a\cdot b=1$. Prove that $R$ is a division ring.

I have almost everything to prove that is a ring with division, I think I only miss the part that $b\cdot a=1$, what I have done so far is the following:

We have $ab=1$ so multiplying $b$ on the left side we have
$$b\cdot a\cdot b=b\cdot 1$$
Since $1$ is the $1$ of $R$, we get:
$$b\cdot a\cdot b=1\cdot b$$
(this is the part I'm not sure about) since we are in a group, we can cancel $b$ on the left side 
$$a\cdot b=1$$
and we are done?

Comment: You haven't proved it's a group yet since $ba$ may not be $1$. But, there must exist $c: bc=1$ so you can actually cancel and therefore $ba=1$, so it's a group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only part you are missing is to show that $ab = 1 \Rightarrow ba = 1$ then proceed as follows:

$$ab = 1 \Rightarrow bab = b $$

Now because of the statement, $b$ has a right inverse, $c $:

$$babc = bc \Rightarrow ba = 1$$

And we are done.

@Alex Wertheim also provides us with a different approach in the comment section. Be sure to check it.

Comment: Perhaps more simply, if $c$ is the right inverse to $b$, then $1c = (ab)c = a(bc) = a1 = a$, so $c = a$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim nicely put. I took my approach because it simply completes what the OP tried

Comment: Understandable, your answer is nice! :) Just thought I'd offer this idea as well.

Comment: ooh i see! thanks! i was missing using again the statement.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to show is that there also exists a left inverse, where for all nonzero $a$, there exists a $b$ so that $ba=1$. Well, you almost had it, the first step was fine, and the idea to "cancel" the $b$ was correct as well, you just need to use the hypothesis on $b$ as well:

let $a$ be nonzero.

Then there exists some $b$ so that $ab=1$. But then $bab=1 \cdot b$. Since $b$ is also nonzero, there exists some $c$ so that $bc=1$. Hence
$$babc=1 \cdot bc \implies ba=1.$$

Answer (score -2):

I think the point is that $a$ and $b$ are non zero, also not zero-divisors. Hence to cancel $b$, you simply multiply $a$ from the left for both sides. However this problem is asking to prove $R$ is a division ring. To me, for every nonzero element in $R$ it has a multiplicative inverse has already been the definition. I don't see what to prove.

Comment: $R$ is not commutative, so the goal is to prove that each element is both left and right invertible.